# ClickOnce console application running from Task Scheduler will not update

Tags: c#, console-application, clickonce, taskscheduler

I have console application deployed to local network drive with ClickOnce (offline). It is meant to run once daily.

**How do I setup a task in the Task Scheduler in such a way that when I publish a new version of the application, the task will run that new version instead of an old one?**

I have successfully created a task to run the application, but when I publish a new version, the task will run the old version. If I update the application manually (by clicking the icon and accepting the update), then the Task doesn't run altogether.

What I do now after deploying is update the app manually and then update the task action. This is a hassle and I'm sure the must be a way to do it.

Comment: Did you uncheck the "Automatically increment revision with each publish" checkbox in the Publish Version section of the Publish tab? If you didn't it will create a new version in a new folder every time instead of overwriting the existing version...

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, however I do like to utilize the incremental revision feature in ClickOnce deployment. I suppose I'd have to write a launcher of sorts to get the latest version? .. but that kinda defeats the purpose of using ClickOnce.